# How to display html content in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very new to angularjs.

I'm trying to display HTML content on the view using AngularJs.
I used `ng-model` but this is showing HTML contents as string there on view.

Now I'm trying `ng-bind-html`, this is working for the first time.
I'm Trying to append the data dynamically. But data is not coming on view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="float: right; width: 60%; height: 500px;" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-bind-html="chatdata"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);

            var a = "";

            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {

                a += "<div style='float: left; width: 70%'>p1 : data1</div>";

                $scope.chatdata = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);

                console.log(a);

                var i = 2;

                var interval = setInterval(function () {

                    if(i === 22 ) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }

                    if (i % 2 === 0) {

                        a = a + "<div style='float: right; width: 70%'>p2 : data" + i +"</div>";
                        $scope.chatdata = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);
                    } else {

                        a = a + "<div style='float: left; width: 70%'>p1 : data" + i +"</div>";

                        $scope.chatdata = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);
                    }
                    console.log(a);
                    console.log($scope.chatdata);
                    i++;
                }, 1000);
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the screenshot data is appending only once.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using **`$scope.$apply()`** and run the complete digest cycle, use

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.chatdata
})
```

Which runs **digest cycle** for only `chatdata`

Running `$scope.$apply() i,e complete digest cycle` affects the performance of the application.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="float: right; width: 60%; height: 500px;" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-bind-html="chatdata"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);

            var a = "";

            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {

                a += "<div style='float: left; width: 70%'>p1 : data1</div>";

                $scope.chatdata = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);

                console.log(a);

                var i = 2;

                var interval = setInterval(function () {

                    if(i === 22 ) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }

                    if (i % 2 === 0) {

                        a = a + "<div style='float: right; width: 70%'>p2 : data" + i +"</div>";
                        $scope.chatdata = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);
                    } else {

                        a = a + "<div style='float: left; width: 70%'>p1 : data" + i +"</div>";

                        $scope.chatdata = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);
                    }
                    console.log(a);
                    console.log($scope.chatdata);
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                      $scope.chatdata
                    })
                    i++;
                }, 1000);
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above SNIPPET**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/n3z1BIzCEJrUoGp5udad?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use 
    `$scope.$apply();`
after assigning value to the chat data at the end of your function.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Inject $timeout in your controller and use it when assigning $scope.chatdata value to tell angular a scope has been updated

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.chatdata = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11245/)